# The way to get all columns used in current SQL from source tables

Tags: sql, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I intend to get the list of all columns used in current SQL from all source tables. For instance:

```
Table X(int a, String b, String e)
Table Y(String c, String d)

SELECT
    X.a
    Y.c
from X
join Y on X.b = Y.c
...
;
```

Then the expected output should be *{"X": ["a","b"], "Y": ["c"]}*, `X.e` and `Y.d` should not appear in the result since they are not used in the previous SQL.

Any idea how to achieve this in Flink SQL? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to do aggregation right?

Comment: @zealous nope, just need a tighter scope of columns list that has been used in current sql from all source tables.